# Right side Command and Option keys are not working (but left ones work as should)

Tags: keyboard

Right side <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>Opt</kbd> keys are not working (with modifiers), but the left ones are working as should on my 2017 15" MacBook Pro running Big Sur, updates are all installed.

What I have tried so far:

1. In **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Modifier Keys** I have tried **Restore Default**.
2. Reset the PRAM.
3. Reset the SMC.
4. Booted in safe mode, however, the issue remains.
5. Created another user account to see if any difference, however, the issue remains.
6. Re-installed Big Sur, however, the issue remains.

In the Keyboard Viewer, the right <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key doesn't highlight when pressed, but the right <kbd>Opt</kbd> does (left <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and left <kbd>Opt</kbd> keys do highlight when pressed in Keyboard Viewer)

Any suggestions for something else I can try?

Comment: Have you tried starting your Mac while pressing the (right) option key. If the boot menu appears that would rule out a hardware issue as it would confirm the issue starts after booting macOS. Same goes for booting with cmd + R for recovery.

Comment: I took the MacBook Pro to apple Store and they said that Apple acknowledges this model is issues with the keyboard, and that they have a Keyboard Service Program for certain models (including this one) to repair/replace keyboard free of charge.

https://support.apple.com/keyboard-service-program-for-mac-notebooks. 

As part of their Keyboard Service Program they changed the keyboard, and the top case which includes the trackpad, and battery. For some reason they also changed the display as well.